# <startswith> attribute cannot be deployed to a Spanish org

Tags: apex, ant

I tried to make a deployment to one of my org's whose language is set to Spanish.

**Setup>>Company Profile>> Company Information >>Change language to Spanish.**

When tried to make a deployment using ANT migration tool,  I encountered the following error:

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Accept</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Clone</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Delete</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Edit</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>List</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>New</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Tab</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    <deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>
    <description>One alloc schedule company object associates one company with one alloc schedule. This identifies which companies should be included in the execution of a scheduled job.</description>
    <enableActivities>true</enableActivities>
    <enableFeeds>false</enableFeeds>
    <enableHistory>true</enableHistory>
    <enableReports>true</enableReports>
    <label>Alloc Schedule Company</label>
    <nameField>
        <label>Alloc Schedule Company Name</label>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <type>Text</type>
    </nameField>
    <pluralLabel>Alloc Schedule Companies</pluralLabel>
    <searchLayouts/>
    <sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
    **<startsWith>Vowel</startsWith>**
</CustomObject>
```

Thanks!

Comment: and the xml where the `startswith` is being used?

Comment: @Eric Added XML in case comment

Answer (score 2):

The `startsWith` element is only used for languages that determine if "a" or "an" should be used: "a car" versus "an orange." For Spanish, use [`gender`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm#meta_type_gender), which takes on one of these values:

> Indicates the gender of the noun that represents the object. This is
> used for languages where words need different treatment depending on
> their gender. Valid values are:
>
> - Masculine
> - Feminine
> - Neuter
> - AnimateMasculine (Slavic languages—currently Czech, Polish, Russian,
>   Slovak, Slovenian, and Ukrainian)

Answer (score 0):

@Eric

Here is the XML

Accept
        Default
    
    
        Clone
        Default
    
    
        Delete
        Default
    
    
        Edit
        Default
    
    
        List
        Default
    
    
        New
        Default
    
    
        Tab
        Default
    
    
        View
        Default
    
    Deployed
    One alloc schedule company object associates one company with one alloc schedule. This identifies which companies should be included in the execution of a scheduled job.
    true
    false
    true
    true
    Alloc Schedule Company
    
        Alloc Schedule Company Name
        false
        Text
    
    Alloc Schedule Companies
    
    ReadWrite
    **Vowel**